# Ubuntu server install: Operation system not found

Tags: boot, server, dell

Laptop is dell xps L502x.
I am able to install ubuntu desktop fine. It boots up and works as it should.

However when I try to do clean install  Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 with all default settings(installation settings such as partitions etc), when it boots up, it says 'Operation system not found'

Bios called phoenix secure tiano setup. I dont see no option for UEFI etc.. has faily limited options to be honest. not sure if it is related.

Comment: UEFI *IS* what you wrongly call "BIOS". So, you may find settings to enable CSM support (legacy) that emulate the old BIOS but explicit settings for UEFI aren't expected in any current firmware. In the "transition" years of a decade ago, give or take, there were references to "UEFI boot mode" or similar. How did you make the USB installation media?

Comment: Dell XPS L502x is a very old laptop that probably still has BIOS.

Comment: I made installation usb with Rufus.

Comment: What option have you selected in Rufus? The problem with Rufus is, unless you used the   DD method, you have to select BIOS/MBR or UEFI/GPT.

Comment: Partition scheme MBR - Target system BIOS or UEFI

Comment: If so it only boots and consequently install in BIOS (Legacy) mode which given the hardware's age is probably correct. Now please check BIOS settings and make sure the boot drive is correct.

Comment: 'Now please check BIOS settings and make sure the boot drive is correct' - Can you elaborate please?

Comment: There's nothing to elaborate about. In BIOS mode the boot loader is installed in the MBR and the boot order in BIOS is determined by a drive selection. You need to be familiar with your own firmware and know where to check this setting.

Comment: Boot order: 
1 USB
2 Hard Drive

Comment: There you are. Try changing to the HDD first. This shouldn't make a difference if there's no USB drive connected but it's worth trying.

Comment: Yea I tried that. No difference. Its very annoying. I think at I ll just install ubuntu desktop again and use that as 'server'.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Pay attention to eventual error messages during installation.